# How to effectively do dynamic query using LINQ against a Azure Cosmos Document DB SQL API?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, azure-cosmosdb

I know that Azure Cosmos DB SQL API allows using SQL syntax to query the documents from it and working for me.

For eg: `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.DynamicContent.MailingAddress.City LIKE '%PORT%'` is working well.

The data I'm trying to save is like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1001,
  "AttentionName": "Keyword list",
  "DynamicContent": {
    "Agency": 2,
    "EnteredOn": "2001-03-30T16:20:00+0000",
    "UpdatedOn": "2001-03-30T16:20:00+0000",
    "Name": "Sample Name",
    "MailingAddress": {
      "Address1": "501 Abbey St",
      "City": "Portland",
      "StateProvince": "OR",
      "PostalCode": "97215",
      "Country": "United States"
    }
  }
}
```

and as the content inside the DynamicContent is unstructured and dynamic, I'm using the below class to save the data:

```
public partial class CosmosDocument
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AttentionName")]
    public string AttentionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DynamicContent")]
    public dynamic DynamicContent { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is not able to do something like this:

```
query.Where(c => c.DynamicContent.MailingAddress.City.Contains("PORT")).ToList();
```

because the properties(dynamic and UI controlled) that may come in the filter are inside a dynamic class and are not strongly typed.

***Is there a way to do this properly or at least some other workaround to achieve this?
Please help with your thoughts.***

Comment: Have you tried object notation? Something like `c.DynamicContent["MailingAddress"]["City"].Container("PORT")`? Please see this blog post: https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/using-linq-to-query-dynamic-schemaless-cosmosdb-documents/.

Comment: Yes, tried. It's giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using LINQ for queries, consider using [`QueryDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.querydefinition?view=azure-dotnet) instead that allows constructing from an arbitrary string and parameter values. There are examples on the [`GetItemQueryIterator` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.GetItemQueryIterator?view=azure-dotnet), for instance:

```
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("select * from ToDos t where t.cost > @expensive")
    .WithParameter("@expensive", 9000);
using (FeedIterator<ToDoActivity> feedIterator = this.Container.GetItemQueryIterator<ToDoActivity>(
    queryDefinition,
    null,
    new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Error")}))
{
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach(var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.cost); 
        }
    }
}
```